# No declaration matches in Codelite IDE

Tags: c++, class, type-declaration

I have been looking in different threads with this error which is quite common but it feels like the IDE I am using messed with my workspace and I can't quite find the problem. I am setting up an extremely basic class called "Movie" that is specified below:

Movie.hpp :

```
#ifndef MOVIE_HPP
#define MOVIE_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string, std::cout,std::size_t;

class Movie
{
private:

    std::string name;
    std::string rating;
    int watched_ctr;
    
public:
    
    Movie(const string& name, const string& rating, int watched_ctr);
    ~Movie();
    
    //getters
    string get_name() const;
    string get_rating() const;
    int get_watched() const;
    
    //setters
    void set_name(string name);
    void set_rating(string rating);
    void set_watched(int watched_ctr);
    
};

#endif // MOVIE_HPP
```

Movie.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Movie.hpp"

using std::string, std::cout,std::size_t,std::endl;

Movie::Movie(const string& name, const string& rating, int watched_ctr)
        : name(name) , rating(rating) , watched_ctr(watched_ctr) {
    }

Movie::~Movie()
{
    cout << "Destructor for Movies class called /n";
}

//Getters
string Movie::get_name(){return name;}
string Movie::get_rating(){return rating;}
string Movie::get_watched(){return watched_ctr;}

//Setters
void Movie::set_name(std::string n){this -> name = n;}
void Movie::set_rating(std::string rating){this -> rating = rating;}
void Movie::set_watched(int ctr){this -> watched_ctr = ctr;}
```

The main.cpp I am trying only consists in creating one Movie object:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "Movie.hpp"
 
using std::string, std::cout,std::size_t,std::endl;

int main()
{
    Movie StarTrek("Star Trek", "G", 20);

}
```

As you can see, I set all the attribute to private in order to exercise with the set/get methods but I keep stumbling upon the same error on each of them stating >"C:/Users/.../ProjectsAndTests/MoviesClass/Movie.cpp:18:8: error: no declaration matches 'std::__cxx11::string Movie::get_name()"

if you could give me a hint on what might cause this error I would greatly appreciate thank you!

I tried opening another workspace with classes implemented inside of them and the syntax I am using is very close from this test workspace I opened which compiled fine (no error regarding declaration match).

Comment: you are missing 'const' on your function definitions. also, the strings you pass to the setters should probably be const references.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thanks for answering. I added the 'const' on my get function definition to match their specification in the .hpp file but I still have the same error. I also changed the setters arguments for const references to string.

Comment: hmm are you sure that the header and the .cpp file in your project are really the ones you think they are?

Comment: I only have one file named Movie.hpp/Movies.cpp in my workspace so it looks like the right files are indeed being called. I am currently doing some testing and it seems that removing the 'const' on the getters seem to fix the issue for some reason. I will keep this thread updated if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code.

**First** while defining the member functions outside class you're not using the `const`. So to solve this problem we must use `const` when defining the member function outside the class.

**Second**, the member function `Movie::get_watched()` is **declared** with the return type of `string` but while **defining** that member function you're using the return type `int`. To solve this, change the return type while defining the member function to match the return type in the declaration.

```
//----------------------vvvvv--------->added const
string Movie::get_name()const
{
    return name;
}
string Movie::get_rating()const
{
    return rating;
}
vvv------------------------------>changed return type to int 
int Movie::get_watched()const
{
    return watched_ctr;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/iT6MLQE-w)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed, like Neil pointed it out, I needed to add the const in the functions declaration. Additionally the type for get_watched was wrong like you said.